# wifi very slow on 17.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

I have a dual boot system in separate disks ( windows 10 & Ubuntu 17.10 ). My wireless adapter is TP-LINK WN822N. When I use Windows 10, Internet speed is about 2.8Mbps. But with Ubuntu, speed falls to 0.8Mbps. According to
 [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos?newreg=7cc595389ad943c8b0ffe78e30551335)
   I have created
https://pastebin.com/uHS5ufFx
to give a full detailed report of my Network.  I appreciate any help

**EDIT**  As Tomáš Pospíšek asked:

```
 tracepath askubuntu.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  speedport-entry-2i.ote.gr                            16.350ms 
 1:  speedport-entry-2i.ote.gr                            16.196ms 
 2:  speedport-entry-2i.ote.gr                            15.809ms pmtu 1492
 2:  80.106.108.1                                         35.786ms asymm  3 
 3:  maro7609a-bras-mar4-e320.backbone.otenet.net         36.435ms 
 4:  nyma-asr99a-maro7609a.backbone.otenet.net            36.507ms 
 5:  62.75.3.157                                          37.052ms asymm  7 
 6:  62.75.6.34                                           86.912ms asymm  7 
 7:  ffm-b10-link.telia.net                               88.176ms asymm 12 
 8:  ffm-bb3-link.telia.net                              110.541ms asymm 11 
 9:  ffm-b1-link.telia.net                                87.875ms asymm 12 
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
............
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1492
     Resume: pmtu 1492
```

Comment: Your `MTU` value is too large (1500) - it should be smaller, e.g. 1492. Install and run `tracepath` to check your `MTU`.

Comment: Thanks waltinator for reply.   "tracepath 192.168.1.10
 1:  home                                                  0.065ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 65535 hops 1 back 1"

Comment: 1. could you tracepath out of your LAN (`tracepath askubuntu.com`). 2. could you insert the command and output nicely formatted into your question?